# How to check if an element is already exists in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a code that check if in my DataGrid a particular element is already exists.
If the elements is already added in the DataGrid the code show a pop-up to the user. This is the code:

```
if (grid.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Items.Count; i++)
                        {

                        if (((Teams.Club_Information)grid.Items[i]).name == reader["name"].ToString())
                        {
                                MessageBox.Show("La squadra è già stata inserita!");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
                                {
                                    name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                                    code = reader["code"].ToString(),
                                    shortName = reader["shortName"].ToString(),
                                    squadMarketValue = reader["SquadMarketValue"].ToString()
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
                        {
                            name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                            code = reader["code"].ToString(),
                            shortName = reader["shortName"].ToString(),
                            squadMarketValue = reader["SquadMarketValue"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
```

In the first condition I check if there's row in the DataGrid, if the condition is true then I iterate through the element of DataGrid.
Now the problem is that I'm compare a grid item with the attribute "name" of the reader. `reader` is the variable the read of the element of a query result (sqlite).
There's another way to check in the column name of my DataGrid if the element is already added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your items are of type "Teams.Club_Information", but you are comparing them to reader["name"] which is a string. Unless you have written an Equals method which will compare Club_Information.name to a string, the comparison will always fail.

Try instead:

```
if (((Teams.Club_Information)grid.Items[i]).name == reader["name"])
```

Comment: I can't see .name variable in the condition

Comment: You will need a way to compare your reader["name"] string value to your Club_Information object. Have you considered adding a public Name property to your Club_Information class which will expose the name value? It appears that currently you have no way of actually comparing the name of your Club to the name you are retrieving in your reader.

Comment: just cast the item to actual type:
`var item = (Teams.Club_Information)grid.Items[i]; If (item.name == reader["name"])`

Comment: Okay but now he always says that the team has already been added while it is not.

Comment: Can you debug your application and find the value of reader["name"] being returned? The application thinks every item in your grid has a name value equal to it. Are you perhaps not breaking out of your loop after adding a new team? Failing to do that would cause your program to try and add the new team many times.

Comment: In your current code you will continue to look for the team after it has been added to the grid, so you will find it when you reach the end of the for loop (as you've just added it to the end of the grid). Try breaking out of your loop after finding or adding a team.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
      if(grid.Items.Contains(reader["name"]))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("team already added");
      }
      else
      {
               MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
               {
                   name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                   code = reader["code"].ToString(),
                   shortName = reader["shortName"].ToString(),
                    squadMarketValue = reader["SquadMarketValue"].ToString()
               });
       }
```

Comment: The solution seems good but if I add the same value as the message appears and then the condition is not true, why?

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = reader["name"];
var isNamePresent = grid.Items
    .Cast<Teams.Club_Information>()
    .Any(item => item.name == name);

if (isNamePresent) ... else ...
```

Comment: the last name, after the equals is underlined in red. With what should replace the last name? Maybe the variable name of the structure ClubInformation? or with the name parameter of the reader?

Comment: I have change `item.Name` to `item.name` in my answer. BTW, intelli sense is very helpfull